# converting queue to linked list when using operator== c++

Tags: c++, list, queue, operator-keyword

I have a queue and a linked list. I am trying to call the operator== function in the linked list through the queue function. The assignment is asking me to compare 2 queues and see if they are the same. I have included the functions from each file that are giving me trouble.

The error message I'm getting is "***C2664  'bool List::operator ==(List &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const Q' to 'List &'***"

queue.h

```
   class Q
   {
   public:
      Q();
      Q(const Q &queue);
      ~Q();
     bool operator==(const Q &queue);
     private:
      List queue;
       };
```

queue.cpp

```
    Q::Q(){}//constuctor

    Q::Q(const Q &queue){}//copy constructor

    Q::~Q(){}//deconstuctor

       bool Q::operator==(const Q &queue1)//this is where the problem is
    {
      return queue.operator==(queue1);

    }
```

list.h

```
    class List
    {
    private:
    struct Node
    {
        int data;
        Node* next;
            Node() : next(NULL) {} //define our own default constructor
        Node(int data) : next(NULL), data(data) {}
    };
     typedef struct Node* NodeRef;

     NodeRef head;
        NodeRef tail;
    NodeRef iterator;
    NodeRef current1;
    int size;
    public:
        List();
    ~List();

    List(const List &list);
    bool operator==(List &queue);// this is where i have the problem
   };
```

list.cpp

```
   bool List::operator==(List& queue)
    {
        if (size != queue.size)
            return false;
       iterator = head;
         NodeRef temp = queue.head;
         while (iterator != NULL)
            {
            if (iterator->data != temp->data)
                return false;
            temp = temp->next;
           iterator = iterator->next;
      }
      return true;
      }
```

main.cpp

```
    Q k,qw;

    if (k == qw)
        cout << "Lists are equal!\n";
    else
        cout << "Lists are unequal!\n";
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to compare like for like, in this case a `Q` only has a `queue` element (which is actually a `List`), so when comparing objects of type `Q`, you need to compare their `queue` elements.

As you already have an `operator ==` for the `List` class, so this is straightforward.

```
bool Q::operator==(const Q &queue1)
{
  return queue == queue1.queue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Right, there are a couple of issues here:

1. `return queue.operator==(queue1);`

   Surely you wanted to use `return queue.operator==(queue1.queue);` or the shorter `return queue == queue1.queue;` to compare the internal `Queue::List`, otherwise, what's the point?
2. `bool operator==(List &queue);`

   This declaration should become `bool operator==(const List &queue);` you basically want to use the const whenever you're not changing anything since it allows you to pass both variables and constants to functions. If you don't do it in this case, your code will break since in point 1 you are passing a const.
3. `bool List::operator==(List& queue)`

   This should become `bool List::operator==(const List& queue)` since definition should match declaration